# Fatal error Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters

Tags: php, pdo

I'm getting a Fatal error when I try to add `$stmt->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);` to my script. Below is just part of my script. What I'm trying to do is get it to use the session username along with id. If I take out the `username = :username` and the `$stmt->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);` it will work fine.

Fatal error I'm getting:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters' in /home/www/test.php:7 Stack trace: #0 /home/www/test.php(7): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in /home/www/test.php on line 7

```
    $action = isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action']: "";
if($action=='delete'){
$username    = $_SESSION['user']['username'];<<<<<<<<I ADD THIS LINE
$query = "DELETE FROM hostingpackage WHERE  username = :username And id = ?";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $_GET['id']);
        $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);<<<<I ADD THIS LINE
        $result = $stmt->execute();
        header("Location: test.php");
        die("Redirecting to test.php");
       }
```

Comment: The error message "mixed named and positional parameters" kind of **spells it out for you**. Don't use both named (`:username`) and positional (`?`) parameters in one query.

Comment: what's wrong with putting `?` at both places in query and using `$stmt->bindParam(1, $username);$stmt->bindParam(2, $_GET['id']);`

Answer (score 1):

As the error says you are attempting to bind param `1` and `:username` in those two statements.  I guess the confusion is the usage of hash notation and `?`.

It's better not to mix the notations, use either `?` throughout or use the hash notation like `:username` throughout.

Please try:

```
$query = "DELETE FROM hostingpackage WHERE  username = :username And id = :id";
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);<<<<I ADD THIS LINE
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $_GET['id']);
$result = $stmt->execute();
```

or this:

```
$query = "DELETE FROM hostingpackage WHERE  username = ? And id = ?";
$stmt->bindParam(1, $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);<<<<I ADD THIS LINE
$stmt->bindParam(2, $_GET['id']);
$result = $stmt->execute();
```